# What does it mean when an input argument to a constructor is set equal to a value in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, arguments

For example, this is found in a header file:

```
SampleConstructor(int hardwareID = INVALID_NODE_ID);
```

Why can't we just do:

```
SampleConstructor(int INVALID_NODE_ID);
```

Comment: That's a parameter with a default value which will be used if you don't pass an argument yourself. This means the class with this constructor is default-constructible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called `default argument`.
It means that you may call the function without specifying any argument and the compiler will use this default argument.

In the example you showed `INVALID_NODE_ID` is some named value (or expression) that can be converted to type int.

Consider for example

```
#include <iostream>

const int DEFAULT_ARGUMENT = 10;

void f( int x = DEFAULT_ARGUMENT ) { std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    f( 20 ); // outputs 20
    f();     // outputs 10 though argument is not explicitly specified
}
```

Relative to the constructor this means that the constructor can be called without an argument. Such a constructor is called **default constructor**.

As for this declaration

```
SampleConstructor(int INVALID_NODE_ID);
```

then here is simply parameter name is typed with upper-case letters. This constructor may not be called without an argument. Though further you can define it as having a default argument. Default argument of member function may be specified either in its declaration or/ and its definition.

Answer (score 0):

First lets remember what a constructor is:

A constructor is a member function which is used to initiate an instance of a class.

What does that mean? It means that every time you make an instance of a class (an object of a class or however you prefer to call it), you first have to get the instance ready. A constructor prepares that instance so that it can be used properly. Even if you don't put a constructor in your code, it will be "secretly" used (well it's no big secret really).

Now, lets say you made a class, and you have some variables declared in that class. If you wanted for instance to make an instance of that class while using variables that weren't defined by default inside the class, you would use the constructor function to change them. If you don't change them, the program "secretly" uses an empty constructor function for you telling your program "I don't want any changes made".

So, to answer your question why you can't do the following:

```
SampleConstructor(int INVALID_NODE_ID);
```

what is INVALID_NOD_ID? it could be a number like 15 or something. Would you ever write the following in your code?:

int 15;

No, because 15 isn't a variable. You have to pass a variable into your constructor function for it then to use that variable appropriately rather than the default value.

The same goes if INVALID_NODE_ID was initiated in the following way:
int INVALID_NODE_ID = 15;
by writing int INVALID_NODE_ID inside the constructor, you would be re-declaring the variable.

Hoped that helped bro.